# how to download protected resources in a jenkins workflow?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

Many times I have the need to download files (e.g. archives) from a remote repository (e.g. maven-repo) which is protected by username/password.

Its easy to get such a file with `curl` or `wget`, but when I don't like to see the password on the logs, maybe there is a better/embedded way to do this from within a jenkins workflow? And how do I combine it with credentials managed by jenkins credential plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Credentials Binding plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin), which integrates with Workflow.