# Jenkins pipeline - ssh to different machine and where to store credentials (using ssh/SSHAgent plugin/etc...)

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, credentials, ssh-agent

**TLDR**: how to ssh a different machine and where to store ssh credentials on Jenkins pipeline (using ssh / SSHAgent plugin /etc...) ?

**The Problem:** In Jenkins pipeline I need a remote ssh to target machine.
My old approach was to use "Execute shell scripts on remote host using ssh". I would like to specify both username and password.

I've read that the groovy approach shoud be something like

```
sshagent(['RemoteCredentials']) {
    sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l remoteusername remotetarget uname -a'
  }
```

RemoteCredentials: it is the private key with passphrase

Is there a way to make ssh with username/password remote credentials? The sshagent does not support username/password auth

Riccardo

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746313/how-to-download-protected-resources-in-a-jenkins-workflow

Comment: you can refer this ssh with user/password https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/02/06/ssh-steps-for-jenkins-pipeline/
sshCommand remote: remote, command: 'for i in {1..5}; do echo -n \"Loop \$i \"; date ; sleep 1; done'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So unfortunately, you're right.

It looks like the ssh-agent-plugin only supports stored user,passphrase,public key credentials added through the Credentials Management area in Jenkins. [See this unit test](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-agent-plugin/blob/1b789b066b255b7955b5562ffb423da0c57fff90/src/test/java/com/cloudbees/jenkins/plugins/sshagent/SSHAgentBase.java) that verifies that ssh-agent is working correctly based around a public key. It's unlikely that there is untested functionality in the plugin to support user+password auth.

**If you can, make the switch to Public Key based authentication. If for some reason you can't switch ... you *COULD* install [sshpass](https://pkgs.org/search/sshpass) on your Jenkins box, but this is generally considered bad practice.**

```
node {
    stage 'Does sshpass work?'
    sh 'sshpass -p \'password\' ssh user@host "ls; hostname; whois google.com;"'
}
```

Comment: Even if you are using this approach, remember to use at least [withCredentials](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) to not expose the password in the Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping up your game running ssh tasks on Jenkins agents, will make your servers more secure. Jenkins is an attack-vector when you run ssh tasks like Ansible, and being in control over releases is desirable.

- Improving /etc/sshd_config will stop a lot of probes by hackers.

  PasswordAuthentication no

  PubkeyAuthentication yes

  PermitRootLogin no
- Move over from DSA or RSA key-pairs to the more secure ed25519 elliptic curve
  cryptography with brute-force protection on the private key-file.

  ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -o -a 300 -C Jenkins

  Because the private key needs hundreds of rounds, each use will take tens of seconds, 
  that is prefect for a build agent where developers might snoop around.

I rather not store the private key as a credential in Jenkins, because Jenkins is a pluggable code execution engine, instead I store only the passphrase as a secret text credential (named mySecretText in the example). I have dedicated agents for environments, each with they own ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 key file with limited blast radius. The passphrase is used to start an ssh-agent, more specifically to load the key per session.

The Jenkinsfile below allows the use of the key-pair to push a tag to git, but there is no plaintext on disk. This implementation was chosen because the ssh-agent plugin did not allow ssh-add.

```
node {
    println("Checkout repository...")
    checkout scm
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        label "linux"
    }

    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }

    stages {
        stage('PushTheTag') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'mySecretText', variable: 'SSH_PASSPHRASE')]) {
                        sh "echo 'echo \$SSH_PASSPHRASE' > ~/.ssh/tmp && chmod 700 ~/.ssh/tmp"
                        sh "eval `ssh-agent -s` && cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519|DISPLAY=None SSH_ASKPASS=~/.ssh/tmp ssh-add - && git tag ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} && git push --tags; kill -9 \$SSH_AGENT_PID"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: You want to ssh some machine in your pipeline. I want to offer a different approach, that is more secured (I want to be able managing my ssh credentials on the machine itself)  . Make sure that your ssh keys is pre built in your infra under `~/.ssh/id_rsa` ( can be preconfigured through ansible/chef/puppet or just use some image snapshot with your aws/gcp/azure cloud environment ). your pipeline should load the ssh private key credentials in the machine and connect to the node (with the public key inside).

```
_node(with private key) ---> testing/staging/production_node(with public key)
```

***When you use it?** Use case for example - you want to run/stop some process in another node, or deploy application on instances x and y in your pipeline*

**Simple example - Point to Point** ( `node -> destination_node` ) would be:

```
def ip-address=<some-ip-address> 

sh """#!/bin/bash
        eval "\$(ssh-agent -s)"
        ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${ip-address} << 'EOF'
        echo 'im in ...'
 """
```

**Complex example - Bastion** using bastion cloud architecture ( `node -> vpc-endpoint -> destination-node`) would be:

```
def vpc-endpoint-gw-ip=<some-ip-address>
def subnet-ip=<some-subnet-address>

sh """#!/bin/bash 
        eval "\$(ssh-agent -s)"
        ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        ssh -At -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${vpc-endpoint-gw-ip} << 'EOF'
        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${subnet-ip} << 'EOF2'
        echo 'im in ...'
  """
```